# c++ error: no matching function for call to 'getline' from within function, but works in main

Tags: c++, c++11

Update: Thanks for the advice! Removing const from my function paramaters and replacing #include  with #include , worked!

---

I'm new to C++ and I've looked up several posts, but can't seem to figure out why I am getting an "error: no matching function for call to 'getline'" from within my user defined function, when it is working fine from the main function.

I also don't understand why in some examples that I've seen online getline takes 2 paramaters (std::istream&, std::string&) and in others it takes 3 parameters (std::istream&, std::string&, char)

Have been racking my brain for a solution, would really appreciate if anyone can point out what I’m missing. sorry if this is a naive question!

condensed code:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib> 

 using namespace std;

 char *myfunction (std::ifstream& infile, const std::string& strBuf){

        //compile error "no matching function for call to 'getline'"
        getline(infile, strBuf);  

        char *ptr= NULL;
        return ptr;
    }



  int main() {
        ifstream infile; 
        infile.open("myfile"); 
        std::string strBuf;

        getline(infile, strBuf);
        // prints the first line of the file as expected
        cout << strBuf << endl;  

    }
```

Comment: You forgot `#include <string>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't read to a `const` object.

Change the argument type from `const std::string&` to just `std::string&`.

```
char *myfunction (std::ifstream& infile, std::string& strBuf)
                                     // ^^ No const 
{
    getline(infile, strBuf);
    ...
}
```

Also, as mentioned in a comment, don't forget to add

```
#include <string>
```